# yum does not work on RHEL 6.3

Tags: linux, yum

I have installed RHEL 6.3:

```
Linux RHEL6.3-64-BuildMac 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My `/etc/yum.conf` looks as follows:

```
[main]  
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever  
keepcache=0  
debuglevel=2  
logfile=/var/log/yum.log  
exactarch=1  
obsoletes=1  
gpgcheck=1  
plugins=1  
installonly_limit=3  
reposdir=/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel.repo
```

The contents of my `/etc.yum.repo.d/rhel.repo` looks like

```
[rhelrepo]  
name=my rhel repo  
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/  
#gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6  
enabled=1  
gpgcheck=0
```

But now when I do "yum repolist" I get the following message:

```
Loaded plugins: security
repolist: 0
```

What do I do to resolve this?

Comment: `/etc.yum.repo.d/rhel.repo` was it typo?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to update a RHEL6 system with a RHEL clone repository. The yum plugins on RHEL6 will not let you update the system that way. You can google for "convert RHEL6 to CentOS" (answers such as http://www.unixmen.com/201201-how-to-convert-rhel-6-x-to-centos-6-x/). Follow the directions and convert your RHEL system to CentOS which will then update. It's less than 10 rpms to convert RHEL to a RHEL-clone.

Answer (score 1):

In your `yum.conf` file, try using:

```
 reposdir=/etc/yum.repos.d
```

instead of the full path to a repo filename.  Yum expects reposdir to be a directory, containing the repo files.

Comment: Hi now my "yum update" commands runs but fails after sometime with the following error Error Downloading Packages:
  redhat-lsb-4.0-3.el6.centos.x86_64: failure: Packages/redhat-lsb-4.0-3.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm from rhelrepo: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Comment: hi i am also getting the following error:[root@RHEL6 ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: security
rhelrep0
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/repodata/5dc95bc0e6520499d90c6ffbad197c9031b13b19f754818dbdb11f31249cb4f6-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/repodata/5dc95bc0e6520499d90c6ffbad197c9031b13b19f754818dbdb11f31249cb4f6-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.

Comment: Have you tried browsing to those URLs from the client machine, to make sure you have an adequate network connection?  If you have poor network, or firewall rules denying access, that could account for your timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

For those getting errors, modify `/etc.yum.repo.d/rhel.repo` (in addition to changing, `reposdir=/etc/yum.repos.d`) and change `baseurl` to:

```
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/
```

They are no longer supporting different versions of 6.x per the readme at:  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3